# Redirect to HTTPS forcefully for Subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, apache

I have published two react application for same domain, one is in root directory and another is in sub directory.

I need to redirect to HTTPS forcefully if some one try with HTTP.
I have added .htaccess files in both directory. And added rules for redirection in both files.

For root directory its working but for sub directory its not redirecting.

If anyone can help me than it would be great full.

For Root Directory :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

For Sub directory :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . subdirectory/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This rule didnt work :

```
RewriteRule ^(subdirectory/.*)$ https://www.sjabjksbasb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see what is in those .htaccess files?

Comment: Yes, I am attaching both .htaccess files.

Comment: I have attached please check.

Comment: There is no redirection rules in any of these files, so there must be something more somewhere...

Comment: can you please share redirection rule for sub directory?

Comment: As i have tried with this but didnt work :